# Linq to entities contains is not working with pre-stored variables

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

Gist of all relevant code: https://gist.github.com/JamesGould123/2207bcec618cac8a3926

In Linq to entities, contains is not working with pre-stored strings. For some reason,

```
string queryStr = "AB7";
var viewModel6 = (from n in db.TableName
                  where n.TableCol.Contains(queryStr)
                  select n.TableCol);
```

returns the query string

```
{SELECT
`Extent1`.`TableCol`
FROM `TableName` AS `Extent1`
WHERE `Extent1`.`TableCol` LIKE '%p__linq__0%'}
```

It unexpectedly replaced the variable `queryStr` with `p__linq__0`.
However,

```
var viewModel5 = (from n in db.TableName
                  where n.TableCol.Contains("AB7")
                  select n.TableCol);
```

returns the query string

```
{SELECT
`Extent1`.`TableCol`
FROM `TableName` AS `Extent1`
WHERE `Extent1`.`TableCol` LIKE '%AB7%'}
```

as expected.

The prestored variables were working fine on my office computer, but on my home computer, no such luck. Why are these two pieces of code not compiling to the same query? How do I get the first  one to compile the same as the second one?

UPDATE: I went to the office and ran git add on the packages folder (we have .dlls gitignored) and backup the db, went home, pulled, recreated the db using the backup, and everything worked again. I assume this was a problem with the version of one of the MySQL packages. I'm leaving the question open in case anybody has a real solution.

Comment: @GertArnold Updated my question to be more verbose: Why are these two pieces of code not compiling to the same query? How do I get the first  one to compile the same as the second one?

Answer (score 0):

there should be no difference between the two query codes.
this is what I get from LINQPAD:

```
string queryStr = "AB7";
var viewModel6 = (from n in this.TbClothes
                  where n.StyleNO.Contains(queryStr)
                  select n.StyleNO);
```

**SQL:**

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(4) = '%AB7%'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[StyleNO]
FROM [tbClothes] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[StyleNO] LIKE @p0
```

Comment: Yes, they definitely should be the same, but for some reason they were not. I just updated my question. I resolved it, but I'm not sure what the exact solution was. Maybe a db problem maybe a MySQL package.